# Understanding an ER Diagram

Tags: database, diagram, entity-relationship

I am new to creating tables from a given ER diagram and while I have worked with crow's foot diagram, I am completely new to the type of diagram below.

**From this, how do I determine the primary, foreign keys in the tables and 1-1, 1-many etc. relationships?**

[image: ER model]

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

***P.S.*** I am trying to model it in MySQL Workbench, so if there are any specific suggestions, I will be obliged!

Comment: one to many is what's in `(0,*)` 0 or many 1,1... as far as pk/fk no fields are defined in some of the tables so you don't know the "Fields" but you do know the cardinalality  A category can be associated to zero or many products a product must have one and only one `(1,1)` category.  A category can have 0 or many categories associated to it `(0,*)` self reflexive)  a shopping cart can have 0 to many `(0,*)` products and a product can be linked to 0 or (many shopping carts)  A shopping cart belongs to one and only one`(1,1)` customer. and a customer may have 0 or 1 shopping carts `(0,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram doesn't contain enough information for you to determine primary or foreign keys in the tables. For example there are no attributes listed for ShoppingCart so it's impossible to say what the keys might be.

However you can determine the relationships fairly easily. The numbers in brackets indicate the *cardinality* of the relationship e.g. (0,*) means "zero or more", (0,1) means "zero or one", (1,1) means "one and only one". So for example from this diagram we can say the a Product can be in "zero or more" instances of ShoppingCart and that a ShoppingCart can have "zero or more" Products, but a Product can belong to "one and only one" Category. A Category can have "zero or one" parents but "zero or more" child categories, and so on.

Comment: So, is the `parent` (in the category table) also a table? I am confused there.

Comment: "parent" describes the relationship, as in "parent-child relationship" - also known as a recursive relationship. In this example a Category can be a superset of other categories (i.e. it is a "parent" category) - it can also be a child of yet another Category. This is a common scenario as it gives you a hierarchy of categories. So the "parent" line in the diagram is showing you that Category has a relationship *to itself*, in a hierarchical fashion.

Comment: Another commonly used example of this is would be "Employee" - some employees report to other employees (or the reverse: some employees manage others) and so the entity "Employee" has a parent-child relationship to itself.